# Self-Hosted VMSS Elastic Agent Pool stopped working after Azure secret expired

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 self-hosted VMSS backed elastic agent pools in Azure DevOps. Earlier today, the secret on the Service Principal used to scale the VMSS expired. I've updated the Service Principal, so it has generated a new secret, but the Scaling jobs seems to have stopped.

The newest event (id 22259, `configurationJob` from the logs below) happened *before* I updated the Service Principal connection.

So it seems like the `sizingJob` stopped executing after the failure during `configurationJob`. I've looked through the Azure DevOps APIs and setting pages, but I can't find any way of getting it to try again.

Is there a delay/schedule on the `configurationJob`, or is there any other way to force it to retry? One solution would be to recreate the pools, but I'd rather not have to do that if it could be avoided.do I need to recreate the agent pools to get them to run again

Output from ElasticpoolLog API call on the pool in question:

```
[
    {
        "id": 22259,
        "poolId": 16,
        "level": "error",
        "operation": "configurationJob",
        "message": "Failed to get scaleset from Azure with error: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://management.azure.com.",
        "timestamp": "2023-10-25T10:04:59.9270943Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 22258,
        "poolId": 16,
        "level": "error",
        "operation": "sizingJob",
        "message": "VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://management.azure.com.",
        "timestamp": "2023-10-25T10:04:59.3096667Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 22255,
        "poolId": 16,
        "level": "error",
        "operation": "sizingJob",
        "message": "VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://management.azure.com.",
        "timestamp": "2023-10-25T10:02:29.5615836Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: After 2 hours the issue resolved itself, so my assumption is that the `configurationJob` is on a 2 hour retry/interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself after 2 hours, so that could indicate that the configurationJob is on a 2 hour retry/interval.

Comment: Your previous secret has expired, so DevOps cannot complete the authentication through the service connection to complete the scale out or scale in operation. After the secret is updated, it can take an hour or more for Azure Pipelines to scale out or scale in the virtual machines. See [How Azure Pipelines manages the scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#:~:text=It%20can%20take,over%20an%20hour.) for more info.

Comment: in order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept the answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!